# SSLMode = verify-full on RDS DB instanse

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-rds

I want to enable mandatory validation of the user's ssl certificate when connecting to a database. I read in the documentation that in the group parameters you need to set the parameters rds.force_ssl = 1 and ssl = 1.

I did it. Restarted the instance, however I can still connect to the database without asking for a certificate. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wrong site, you'd need [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon-rds).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `require_secure_transport` parameter to require that all user connections to your MySQL DB instance use SSL/TLS. By default, the `require_secure_transport` parameter is set to `OFF`. You can set the `require_secure_transport` parameter to `ON` to require SSL/TLS for connections to your DB instance.

You can set the `require_secure_transport` parameter value by updating the DB parameter group for your DB instance. You don't need to reboot your DB instance for the change to take effect.

When the `require_secure_transport parameter` is set to ON for a DB instance, a database client can connect to it if it can establish an encrypted connection. Otherwise, an error message similar to the following is returned to the client:

`MySQL Error 3159 (HY000): Connections using insecure transport are prohibited while --require_secure_transport=ON.`

Comment: what if I use postgres and there is no such parameter?

Comment: Can you follow this link for Postgresql
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.SSL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.SSL.Requiring:~:text=sslmode%3Dverify%2Dfull-,Requiring%20an%20SSL%20connection%20to%20a%20PostgreSQL%20DB%20instance,-You%20can%20require

Comment: I can, but it describes exactly the same thing that I have already tried. But the server does not require a certificate from the client anyway, but allows you to freely connect to the database